# Setup of DHCP server

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp

I am trying to rise a server to boot OS from network.
The last thing I must do is to setup DHCP. I found an instruction on the Internet but encountered some problem..
Instruction says type

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf
```

and then correct this file. But the problem is I do not have this directory! I have dhcp directory but some files from there are missing. For example next point of the instruction is: open `/etc/default/dhcp3-server` and make corrections there.. I also have no dhcp3-server! 
I installed dhcp-server using command `sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server` but have some files missing.

The last problem  is: I must correct one line in /etc/default/dhcp3-server. 
I must change it to `INTERFACES="eth0"` , but `ifconfig` is saying me that I have only three interfaces eno1, lo and wlo1. No eth0!

What should I do with these ?
Thanks in advance!

P.S.
distr. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 1
Once again briefly - files dhcp3-server and dhcp3 are missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your version of DHCP, path may change. In your case, the dhcp configuration may be in `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`. The service configuration would be in `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`.

If your system does not have an `eth0` device, then obviously, you should pick some device you have locally (probably `eno1`) instead.